# Sonar violation to show Java files without license/copyright information?

Tags: java, code-analysis, sonarqube, static-code-analysis

Is there a Sonar plugin available, which is able to identify Java files without a license/copyright header?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you just have to activate one of the following rules on your Java quality profile, and the files w/o a header will have a violation after the next analysis:

- "Header" (Checkstyle: com.puppycrawl.tools.checkstyle.checks.header.HeaderCheck)
- "Regexp Header" (Checkstyle: com.puppycrawl.tools.checkstyle.checks.header.RegexpHeaderCheck)

See [them on Nemo](http://nemo.sonarsource.org/rules_configuration/index/7?searchtext=header&plugins%5B%5D=&priorities%5B%5D=&rule_status=INACTIVE&inheritance=&commit=Search) for instance.

Comment: Perfect, exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: Ok, it seems there is no way to limit that to only java files. I don't want CSS, HTML, XML, etc. files getting parsed. Any way to do that?

Comment: If you specify your project propertly (i.e. with a source folder that contains only your Java code, like "src/main/java"), you shouldn't have any problem.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is too simple assumption. For example, in GWT properties files must be located in the same package as the class getting localised, see: https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideI18nConstants There are many more examples which can't be moved out of src/main/java.

Comment: OK, I understand. However, why don't you apply license header to the other files? They are actual source code, like Java files. And if you want to protect your code with copyright, you should do it on every source file.

Comment: Yes, that would be the solution in the long run, but means a lot of effort as we are having a huge code base. Also, the regex form in Sonar is very strange. Everytime I enter a backslash and click update, it escapes the backslash. Not sure how that is supposed to work...

Comment: Another solution would be using Regexp Singleline Java (com.puppycrawl.tools.checkstyle.checks.regexp.RegexpSinglelineJavaCheck), but that one only triggers if a certain line was found. So it is missing the option illegalPattern=false to reverse the logic.

Comment: At SonarSource, we use [Maven License Plugin](http://code.google.com/p/maven-license-plugin/) in our CI process to add header to missing files and check existing files. This can handle lots of different file types. Maybe this could help you.